# Слово, що означає погану роботу приладів? (англійською "on the fritz")

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, одним-словом

Яке розмовне слово можна використати для опису поганої роботи електричного чи механічного приладу?

Наразі знайшов слово "збоїти", що мене влаштовує, проте можливо є інші цікаві варіанти (за контекстом перекладу було б гарно якесь яскраво розмовне слово чи фраеологізм, бо "збоїти" значно ближче до "malfunction", ніж до "on the fritz")?

Comment: Як щодо «заїдає» або «глючить»?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [**Барахлити**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=180106&page=111)
>
> Погано працювати (звичайно про мотор, машину).

або

> [**Фуричити**](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53412/376218.html)
>
> Діяти, працювати, функціонувати (про якийсь механізм).
>
> Відповідно — **погано фуричити**.